# Find and extract then replace for each line in each file

Tags: php

If i have a set of text files in a directory and each file has lines as following

```
-->1, one
#aline
#bline
-->2, one
#aline
#bline
#cline
-->3, one
-->4, one
```

I would like to extract the number that is between `-->` and `,`
then replace `#` with it with respect to each sub-line so it be like

```
-->1, one
1aline
1bline
-->2, one
2aline
2bline
2cline
-->3, one
-->4, one
```

Let's make it simple, and here is my try

```
// getting files into array
foreach (glob('\www\lab\*.txt') as $path_to_file) {

// open each file and put lines into array
    $file_contents = file_get_contents($path_to_file);

    $lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $file_contents);

    $new_lines = [];

// now let's work on each line
    foreach ($lines as $line) {

// 1- extract the number
        if (strpos($line, '-->') !== false) {
            // will get any number between > and ,
            preg_match('~>(.*?),~', $line, $output);
            // now the number saved  in $elnumber variablle
            $elnumber = $output[1];

// 2- how to re-loop again and replace # with $elnumber value

            foreach ($lines as $line) {
                if (strpos($line, '#') !== false) {
                    $new_lines[] = str_replace('#', $elnumber, $line);
                }
            }
        }

    }

// save the file
    file_put_contents($path_to_file, implode(PHP_EOL, $new_lines));
}
```

the results are a blank file! i  had a feeling that iam so close to achieve this but still needs help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have there nested loops, don't store current line/number, etc.

Check this code, it returns what you need (of course, I used string, you'll change `$str` for your file).

```
<?php

$str = '-->1, one
#aline
#bline
-->2, one
#aline
#bline
#cline
-->3, one
-->4, one';

$str = explode(PHP_EOL, $str);

$new_lines = [];
$last_num = '';

foreach ($str as $line) {
    if (strpos($line, '-->') !== false) {
        preg_match('~>(.*?),~', $line, $output);
        $last_num = $output[1];
        
        $new_lines[] = $line;
    } else {
        $new_lines[] = str_replace('#', $last_num, $line);;
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($new_lines);  // here will be file_put_contents

/*
Output:

Array
(
    [0] => -->1, one
    [1] => 1aline
    [2] => 1bline
    [3] => -->2, one
    [4] => 2aline
    [5] => 2bline
    [6] => 2cline
    [7] => -->3, one
    [8] => -->4, one
)
*/
```

Comment: this is very smart way, i was thinking about this but wasn't able to achieve it, thanks a lot that was very helpful to me.

Comment: Maybe in the regex could be `\d` instead of `.*`, maybe substr+strpos will be a little bit faster... It's just about time optimalization, I worked with your current code.